# R and RStudio won't open Mac OS X 10.10.5

Tags: r, rstudio

I have been using R & RStudio for around a year now. When trying to open RStudio, it would keep loading, or give me a blank RStudio page. I read the [RStudio Desktop Would Not Start](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488508-RStudio-Desktop-Will-Not-Start), and other helpers, and I think there was a connection issue with R, so I deleted both R & RStudio. I then downloaded RStudio again, the latest version, and downloaded R 3.3.3, because I'm using a Mac OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5 and therefore can't get R 3.4. Anyway, so, when I re-downloaded R, it would open, but my mouse would just keep spinning and it wouldn't work or it would instantly crash. I couldn't type anything or do anything.

Here is what it currently looks like. My mouse would also be spinning, and it would slow my entire computer down. 
[image]

I tried removing files such as .Rprofile, .Renviron, and .RData, but that didn't work.

I also still can't open RStudio.

If I type Sys.which("R") in my Terminal I get this error:

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"R"'.  "

Would anybody please, please be able to help? I really miss using R & RStudio and am out of ideas.

Comment: It seems it is trying to load your data from previous session. You can try to remove or rename the file `/Users/julienassouline/.RData`.

Comment: @Marcelo Thanks! I was able to fix this by removing the .RData file, by finding it in the hidden files in my computer.